# send text value for ajax popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

here is my javascript

```
<script>    
  jQuery(function ($) {

    $('.button').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax.php',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (html) {
                $('body').append(html);
                $(html).bPopup();
            },
            error: function (returnValue) {}
        });
    });


});
  </script>
```

Here is my html

```
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty">
<button type="button" class="button small cart-button" data-id="xxxx">Add to Cart</button>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?> // show id : xxxx
```

I want to send `qty value` for `ajax.php` file. so how to do it i want to echo it from php.. plz help me for this... thanks

Comment: You need attribute "data-id" then what else? Your question is not clear

Comment: this is add to cart system.. i want to send quntity value send from click button
if u can plz check this url : http://www.sriads.com/shopping/product/13/tp-link-4-port-wireless-dual-band-n600

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
<script>    
  jQuery(function ($) {

    $('.button').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var qtyValue = $("input[type='text'][name='qty']").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax.php',
            data: {
                id: id,
                quantityValue : qtyValue  
            },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (html) {
                $('body').append(html);
                $(html).bPopup();
            },
            error: function (returnValue) {}
        });
    });


   });
</script>
```

Comment: popup not work plz check link : http://www.sriads.com/shopping/product/13/tp-link-4-port-wireless-dual-band-n600

Comment: now poup work but how to echo it ?
i tried `<?php echo $_POST['qtyValue']; ?>`

Comment: Try $_POST['quantityValue']

Comment: Actually I dont know PHP. One of my friend Bharat helped me. He only  told me to use "$_POST['quantityValue'] ".  :)